# Intellij IDEA jstl and taglibs not recognized even after adding dependency

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm trying to incoporate `jstl` and `taglibs` dependency to my project. But `Intellij IDEA` won't recognize the `<c:url value="" />` tag.

Here's my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.emusicstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>emusicstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here's a link href line where I tried to put the `<c:url..>` tag

```
<title>Carousel Template for Bootstrap</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here's the screenshot. It appears that it's not recognizing the `<c:url >` tag and value (in quotes) like it's identifying the path as plain text.

[image]

What could be causing this and how can I resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `c:url` tag (or any other tag from **core** group of JSTL tags) in your JSP page, you need to include the [JSTL Core](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) library:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Supposing you have the following project structure:

[image]

you can use relative path to your `bootstrap.min.css` file:

```
<link href="<c:url value="../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

or using your [`contextPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29):

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/src/main/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know I have to add the URL. I had to add <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" /> in my dispatcher-servlet.xml though. I'll take note of the information you provided. I appreciate it.